# How to make `objcopy` support efi-app target?

Tags: gnu, binutils, objcopy

The following makefile snippet seems to `objcopy` command line options to convert a `.so` file into a `.efi` file.

```
OBJCOPYFLAGS = \
    -j .text\
    -j .sdata\
    -j .data\
    -j .dynamic\
    -j .dynsym\
    -j .rel\
    -j .rela\
    -j .reloc\
    --target=efi-app-$(TARGET)   <=====HERE
```

It basically extract certain sections from the `.so` file and into a `efi-app` target.

But when I use `objcopy --info` to view all the supported output file formats (see below), there's no `efi-app` type.

[image]

So how to make `objcopy` support `efi-app` output format?

### ADD 1

Found a related link:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7197314.html

It seems I need to consider Gentoo Linux distribution and the [gnu-efi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnu-efi/?source=navbar) project.

Add the quote below in case the link the broken.

Question:

> I was interested in learning how to create UEFI applications. I
>   installed the gnu-efi ebuild and found in the readme that objcopy
>   needs to support efi-app-x86_64. when I do objcopy --help, there is no
>   mention of efi-app-x86_64. I tried adding the multitarget useflag with
>   no luck. I was wondering if anyone knows how to get a toolchain that
>   supports efi or if there are any goosd tutorials ( I have not been
>   able to find any) about using gentoo/linux to build efi apps.

Answer:

> First of all, Gentoo's GNU-EFI is at version 3.0i, which is extremely
>   old (September, 2009). The current version is 3.0s, although in my
>   tests it doesn't work so well (binaries fail to execute). Version 3.0r
>   works fine for me, so you might want to try downloading it from its
>   Sourceforge page and installing it locally. FWIW, I filed a bug report
>   requesting a version bump in April of this year, but it's gotten no
>   official action, although this bug report includes links to local
>   ebuilds.
>
> As to your main question, my objcopy also doesn't show efi-app-x86_64
>   as a target, but it does work. Here's what I get for supported
>   targets:

Code:

```
objcopy: supported targets: elf64-x86-64 elf32-i386 elf32-x86-64 a.out-i386-linux pei-i386 pei-x86-64 elf64-l1om elf64-k1om elf64-little elf64-big elf32-little elf32-big plugin srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
```

> When I compile my rEFInd using GNU-EFI, I get the following (among
>   many other messages) in the make output:

Code:

```
/usr/bin/objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel \
      -j .rela -j .reloc --target=efi-app-x86_64 refind_x64.so refind_x64.efi
```

> This doesn't produce any error, and in fact the binary works fine.
>
> So the bottom line is: Don't worry about it unless it gives you
>   problems. If that's the case, post back with details.
>
> One more point: It's possible to compile EFI applications using the
>   TianoCore EDK2 rather than GNU-EFI. TianoCore is a complete EFI
>   implementation, so it's overkill just to compile EFI applications, but
>   it can do the job. It's also got a weird (by Linux standards)
>   compilation process, which can make it awkward to install and use from
>   Linux. Most EFI programs developed for Linux users, such as the new
>   Shim security tool and gummiboot boot loader, use GNU-EFI and won't
>   compile with TianoCore. OTOH, TianoCore is much more up-to-date than
>   GNU-EFI, and it's the better choice if you want to compile something
>   developed with TianoCore or its predecessor development kits, such as
>   an EFI shell program. Some tools, such as rEFInd, can be compiled
>   either way. (rEFInd's ability to boot BIOS/legacy boot loaders depends
>   on TianoCore features, though; you can't launch BIOS/legacy boot
>   loaders if you compile rEFInd with GNU-EFI.) You can look at rEFInd's
>   BUILDING.txt and Makefiles to learn how to use TianoCore in a more
>   Linux/Unix-like manner. In the end, which tool is best may depend on
>   what you want to compile (which specific existing program or your own
>   program that you're writing from scratch). If you're writing a new
>   program, understanding the EFI features you want to use may be
>   important.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking at generating 64-bit UEFI apps recently. From what I gather, `efi-app-x86_64` gets translated by binutils to `pei-x86-64`. So I assume `efi-app` gets translated to `pei-i386`.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Mailing list post that gave me the clue: https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/binutils/2018-12/msg00109.html